# MySQL foreign key clause on create statement causing lost connection error

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL 5.5.43-0+deb8u1 and trying to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car_favorites` (  
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED auto_increment ,  
  `user_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  `car_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  
  `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,  
  `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,  
  `deleted_at` DATETIME,   
  UNIQUE `user_id_car_id` (`user_id`, `car_id`),   
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,   
  FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `cars` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8;
```

The referenced tables `users` and `cars` already exist. When I try to run this query I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Afterwards, the table is listed when do something like `SHOW TABLES`, but if I try to execute a query against the table (i.e. `DESCRIBE car_favorites`) the service reports that the table doesn't exist, and restarting the service makes the table disappear.

However, when I remove this part of the query:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`car_id`) REFERENCES `cars` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The table is created with no problems. Strangely, if I run this query:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

immediately after running the failing create query, there are no foreign key  errors shown or listed. Turning up MySQL logging and examining the error log shows this rather vague error:

```
13:21:41 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
```

Followed by a stack trace and some other info, but nothing specific.

I have no idea why this foreign key clause is causing this crash. Any insight or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Through the process of writing this question, I found the answer. Fairly obvious if you actually take a breath and read the create query.

Since I declared the column `car_id` with `NOT NULL`, then the `ON DELETE SET NULL` part of the foreign key declaration doesn't make any sense. Changing that clause to `ON DELETE CASCADE` solved the problem.

Why MySQL chokes hard and can't give me a more specific error, I have no idea.

Comment: The short answer: it shouldn't do that.  The longer answer, "*InnoDB: Removal of a foreign key object from the data dictionary cache during error handling caused the server to exit. (Bug #20442523)*" [fixed in the next version, 5.5.44](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-44.html) might be the culprit.  It's not a public bug, so it's difficult to say, but it sounds pretty convincing.